# How to bring a Table View Cell's content view above all other Table View subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Scenario -**
I have a table view on which I have added custom views by `tableView.addSubView(myView)`.

Now I have a certain cell whose contentView needs to be shown above tableView.

**Methods Tried**

I tried passing a tag on the cell's contentView and iterating on all table view's subView's. But that didn't help out.

***How to move a cell's contentView above any other sub views of table view?***

Comment: you can tell the tableview to move back the `myView` by using the following code `tableview.sendSubview(toBack: myView)`.Instead of bring the cells to front

Comment: But that would move "myView" to back of all cell's.

Comment: Yeah.. You want to show the cell's content view only right. Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: I want to show only one particular cell's contentView to front.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to add subviews to tableviews... What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DonMag I have had a complicated view for that. I know thats not a good practice, but do we have a solution for this?

Comment: A solution for what? It is not at all clear from your description what you are trying to do... *"move a cell's contentView above..."*??? Can you post an image (screen shot of a "mock up") of what you want?